# hapi set header before sending response

Tags: javascript, node.js, header, handler, hapi.js

In a hapi handler I try to set a header of my response earlier in the code before sending back a view.

```
reply().header('cache-control', 'no-cache');

{....}

reply.view('myView', myContext);
```

Do you I have to use the `hold` method? In that case how do I reuse the response when rendering the view?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: breaking changed since hapi v.17 please check my answer.

Answer (score 8):

/**************** BREAKING CHANGES SINCE HAPI V.17 ****************/

Breaking changes since hapi v.17 real breaking changes most of codes and libraries and apis changed and prev boiler plates or guides cant help much. So you need to look for new articles tagged with hapi v.17

api page: https://hapijs.com/api#response-toolkit

First `reply()` is not valid and you should use `reply.response()`

Second in new guides the `reply` is changed with `h` its argument so can be named anything but as the guides are using `h` so you may use h as well.

Third the `hold()` is not defined and well and its not needed.

Forth the `send()` is not needed or even not define i think.

And some other changes. Please check the api link above.

so this is part of code I wrote should give some good information. dont care about the whole function just look at the h and the response section

```
static _json_response(res, request = null, h = null){
        let ret = '';
        ret = JSON.stringify(res);
        if (request == null || h == null){
                return ret;
        }else{
                const response = h.response(ret)
                        .header('cache-control', 'no-cache')
                        .type('application/json')
                return response;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

set header on each response
currently tested in hapi 6.6.0

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', function(request, reply) {

 request.response.header('X-API-VERSION', '0.0.1');

 reply();

});
```

Comment: breaking changed since hapi v.17 please check my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the hold method as follows

```
reply.hold();
reply.view('your-view');
```

or even

```
reply.view('your-view').hold();
reply.send();
```

the reply is held until you call the .send() method, hence:

```
reply().header('cache-control', 'no-cache').hold();
...
reply().send();
```

is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: breaking changed since hapi v.17 please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
var response = request.view('myView', myContext).header('cache-control: no-cache').hold();

// other stuff

response.send();
```

Comment: The thing is at the point I want to set my header I don't have myContext yet. That is why I would like to prepare my response by setting the header earlier and later on send the view back

Comment: breaking changed since hapi v.17 please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is what I've done (not sure it is the best solution):

```
var response;    
{...}
response = reply().header('cache-control', 'no-cache').hold();
{...}
response = response || reply.view('summary', summary).hold();
response.send();
```

That works

Comment: breaking changed since hapi v.17 please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for an answer for a non-view response with Hapi v17+.

Individual responses are sent using the response toolkit which is referred to as `h`

```
h.response(response).code(statusCode).header('header-here', 'header-value-here);
```

Alternatively you can a header for all responses using the onPreResponse event

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', (request, h) => {
 request.response.header('x-123', '123');
 return h.continue;
});
```